# Do Corona apps have a native look and feel on Android/IPhone?

Tags: iphone, android, coronasdk

Do Corona apps have a native look and feel on Android/IPhone? I am asking as it seems to have a lot of good applications for it, but they all seem to be games only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll first qualify this by saying I haven't USED Corona but I have looked into it some.

Corona has something called the CoronaUI that looks very native. Unfortunately, I don't think you can test it without purchasing the SDK as, last I knew, it was not included in the free, trial download.

CoronaUI Video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9UHNSRilB-0

**UPDATE:** I spent a good chunk of yesterday actually working with the trial SDK. I can't find anything about the CoronaUI. The video I linked to was posted in February but I don't see *any* more information about it. Maybe I missed something but beyond a few native lists it seemed very game focused. I would think if CoronaUI was something you only got with the license they would at least make the docs available so I could see what I was missing!

Comment: The CoronaUI you mention here is the old open-source version, which was released. That has now been deprecated in favor of the new user interface "widget" library: http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/widget

Answer (score 0):

See the new user interface "widget" library here:
http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/widget

Those are native-looking interface widgets. Right now it is in beta but progress is ongoing. Android widgets coming as the feature progresses.